# How do I stick paper on the wall in a stylish manner?

Tags: design

I want to stick some papers on my room wall, some paintings and notes ..

but looking for a way that it looks fashion.

Any ideas about that?

Comment: Do you have any more information about the type of "papers" and the wall itself?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for missing necessary information. wall has wall-paper on it and papers are simple A4 papers. I want to choose some of them I like more and  print them out.

Comment: [Gorilla Glue](http://www.gorillaglue.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Framing them would be one obvious suggestion.
- get a wire curtain hanger from Ikea, then use clothes pins/alligator clips to hang your prints from
- check your office store for A4 clear sleeves you'd normally find in a binder. Think of a creative way to hang them
- cork board strip
- attach a strip of metal to the wall from your big box hardware store and use magnets to attach your drawings

Comment: How to frame them? and I didn't get the second one. other suggestions would not work here.

Comment: You could take them to a frame shop, or buy your own frames and mattes, or buy prematted frames at Target/Walmart/etc, or consider poster frames...there's lots of options. The second suggestion is something like this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_7RWnKewFsi8/TU2Wvlq84HI/AAAAAAAAAGo/P0IqYqq1lMM/s1600/wire+art+hanger+005.jpg

Comment: +1 for alligator clips. Independent art galleries are doing this more and more, so you know it's trendy! Just make sure to find a kind of clip that won't damage your paper. Also helps if the paper you're hanging is thicker, like card stock. You could always mount a sheet of paper on card stock too for a cheap matte look.

Answer (score 3):

This [post](http://lifehacker.com/5764512/give-your-walls-lively-but-temporary-color-with-fabric) describes a method of hanging fabric on a wall with spray starch.  The same technique may work with paper.  The benifit is easy removal without damaging the existing wall.